# iOS: Testing device to allow access to photo library...reset setting

Tags: ios, photolibrary

I was testing my app, part of which allows the user to take a photo and save it. When the alert appeared on the screen asking me to give my app access to the photo library I accidentally hit "No" (Stupid touch feature : D ). Now each time I run the app I cannot save images. Is there a way to reset that?

Comment: Look at my answer Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33940858/1415713

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn access on in the settings. Settings->Privacy->Photos->Your App.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even check there. I thought for some reason it would refresh each time I did a build.