# iOS resetting granting access to reminders

Tags: ios, permissions, reset, reminders

I have a silly problem, one of you surely already encountered.

I am working on adding reminder/alarm in my app and I am using : eventStoreAccessGranted.

It all works fine. When I installed the app for the first time, I got asked if I want to grant access to the app, I said yes and then I got my reminder/alarm, as I programmed it.

I need to test more though and especially because I am localizing I want to write down the question of "granting access to add reminders" in the several languages I am using. Problem is, I got asked once and that's it, I don't get asked again.

I tried killing the app and deleting it from my phones completely, but when I reinstall it, my answer yes is still stored somewhere because I don't get asked. So in my iPhones, I went to settings/privacy/reminders,I could see my app and I turned the switch to off, but then when I reinstall the app, it NSLogs me that "Access hasn't been granted", what is true.

How can I delete in settings/privacy/reminders, the line showing my app and the switch ON/OFF, please ? In other words, how can I be asked again, please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reset the privacy settings in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596165/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-privacy-settings-in-ios)

Answer (score 2):

Just a little hack:
If you want to see the Access Alert for different accesses (fotos, reminders, push and so on) during development, you can use this hack:

1. make sure your Code Signing Identity has a star (*) in the end, like this:
   [image]
2. Change your bundle Identifier significantly: Example:
   your bundle identifier is: de.kurtsalman.**myAppName** --> change it to --> de.kurtsalman.**myAppName2345** (or any other)

on every change (you have to change it anytime you want to see the alert view again) just start simulating on device (cmd+R) - Now you will get everytime an alert.

If its to stupid for you, to change always the bundle-ID for testing, you can create a script in your build phases, to rewrite the bundle identifier for anytime you Run your App on your test device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

> Settings --> General--> Reset--> Reset Location&Privacy

Comment: Hi Anil, no I didn't, because it then would reset all the apps for location and privacy and I would have to do it all over again for the rest of the apps. You don't know if we can do it only for selected apps ?

Comment: I dont know exactly. But nothing will happen even if you reset all. Whenever you reopen the apps, again it will ask for the permission

Comment: In case it helps somebody else, I found an other stack overflow post with this info : "Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

To simulate a first-time run of your app, leave the app uninstalled for a day. or follow these steps:

Delete app from the device.
Turn the device off and turn it back on.
Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
Turn the device off again and turn it back on."

It's a bit of a pain but it also works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Try testing in the Simulator and reset location & privacy each time. It worked for me when I was testing for EKAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined. I don't enjoy the simulator but it got the job done.